# Hide the whole metabox cmb2

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm using the famous [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2) to create custom metaboxes, i want to have one hidden field with default value which i will set myself. i used this [hidden field type](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#hidden) and its working fine , the thing is the metabox will have this field only, so i ended up with what looks like an empty metabox which may confuse the user. i have read [dispaly options](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Display-Options) but this controls where should the metabox appear, i have it exactly where i want on my posts but i want to set it's visability to be hidden so i do not confuse the user , i thought about using css on this but i want to check if there is a way to achieve this using CMB API

Answer (score 0):

i'm adding the css way answer because it works and achieves the requirement , but i would still like to know if there is another php way for educational purpose.

```
function admin_style() {
wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/admin-css.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```